# Yii with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am embedding bootstrap with yii,and have found the following extension  http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/.Is it better to use this package or is there any advanced and more better options available.I am just a beginner in yii.

Answer (score 3):

YiiBooster much impressing than yii bootstrap ,try this

http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/

Answer (score 1):

even better use Yiistrap, it was coded using yii booster and yii boostrap